# How to change the background colour of different components in Angular2?

Tags: html, css, angular

In an Angular2 app, there is a problem I keep encountering, i.e, setting the background colour or image of a page. In the app, if I mention a particular colour in the styles.css for the background then that colour is applied for all the pages I develop, since it applies the styles globally. Now If my login page is blue in colour and I want to change the background colour of my home page to white, how do I go about doing that? Because in the component Homepage we have : homepage.component.html and homepage.component.css . In homepage.component.css, the css only affects the elements of the homepage. I cannot change the colour of the entire page or add an image as a background for the entire page either since 
`body { ... }` will not work there. Neither does @import url work.

How can I change the background colours of different components in an Angular2 app?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an other solution. It is maybe a little basic,restrictif or hacky, but it works:

**style.css**

```
 body, html {
   padding: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   ...
 }

.my-container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  ...
}
```

**home.component.css**

```
.my-container{
    background-color: red;
 }
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="my-container">
   ...
   /* the content of your component here */
</div>
```

**login.component.css**

```
.my-container{
    background-color: blue;
 }
```

**login.component.html**

```
<div class="my-container">
   ...
   /* the content of your component here */
</div>
```

and so on.

Comment: I had tried this. But then the margins become a problem.There are these white spaces around the div.

Comment: Look at your body{} in style.css you should have padding: something ?

Comment: No there is no padding in styles.css

Answer (score 4):

```js
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,

})
```

To override the styles in the styles.css and specify specific styes for the compoenent add  **ViewEncapsulation as none** into your component and import the right class, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:host` selector to apply styles in the host component’s template, the one that is parent to the current component. In your component's css, try this:

```
:host .my-app-class {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Not helping. I kept it in app.component.css, didn't work there so I kept it in dashboard.component.css, it didn't work there as well. Whatever was there in styles.css prevails.

Comment: Add some class to you app component selector  and change that with host.

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution.

**style.css**

```
.login-page {
    height: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(104, 145, 162), rgb(12, 97, 33));
}
```

**login-home.component.ts**

keep the eye in the **OnInit** and **OnDestroy** functions

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-home',
  templateUrl: './login-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-home.component.css']
})
export class LoginHomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  // Search the tags in the DOM
  bodyTag: HTMLBodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  htmlTag: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // add the css-style to the html and body tags
    this.bodyTag.classList.add('login-page');
    this.htmlTag.classList.add('login-page');
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // remove the the body classes
    this.bodyTag.classList.remove('login-page');
    this.htmlTag.classList.remove('login-page');
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a 3 years old post, and I don’t know if this works in Angular 10

Comment: didn't work for me in 2022

Answer (score 0):

So, I've also faced this problem, and i found a solution.

Go to you `component.ts` file and add this piece of code below your `styleUrls` under the `@component`.

```
   /../
   styleUrls: ['./xyz.component.css'],
   styles:[
       `
        :host{
            display:block; //can be anything except inline(default display)
            background-color: white; //any background color you want
        }
       `
   ]
```

It worked for me, hope it works for you as well.